# How hot do High Power 1-3W LEDs get

Tags: led, temperature

I'm thinking of Using 3W RGB high power LEDs for a project. I will only have one color on at a time so I'm pretty sure that it would be 1W of ussage at a time. (please correct me if I'm wrong) My question is how hot do they get? I'm planing to use heat sink but trying to gauge if this is realistic for my project or will these be too hot for what I want to use them for. Nothing I read talks about temperatures it just says "they get hot!"

Comment: They get hot. really hot. That is all.

Comment: If you actually want to know, the manufacturer datasheet will tell you the thermal resistance for the product. It may be something like 60 degrees/Watt. They may state that with certain heatsinks, you can get more like 20 degrees/Watt. So if you have a heatsink which does that, you can run the LED at Ambient temp + 20 degrees/Watt for example.

Comment: Can you link us to the datasheet and we can point that stuff out for you?

Comment: china is cheap guys... Here is the link of what I bought... Don't think they have the data sheet :( http://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCSX3W-Super-bright-LED-Light-Cool-White-Warm-White-Red-Green-Blue-High-Power-Led-chip/1615267898.html

Comment: They boast "*low thermal resistance*", but don't provide the actual number.  Which brings us to the **cardinal rule:**  *No datasheet ⇒ No sale*

Comment: From my experience using 3W and 10W LEDs, without a heatsink they definitely cannot do their rated current. but with that star shaped alloy backplate heat sink, these will do 3W without failing. They will still be extremely hot, probably running at 100 degrees or close to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a datasheet, you could figure this out empirically.  Run a known amount of current (start with very small currents to try and avoid self-heating) through each of the 3 diodes and measure the Vf and temperature (you can get close on temperature without measuring the junction since the thin dielectric of the MPCB has very low thermal impedance).  From this you can calculate a rough thermal impedance.  Repeat for various ambient temperatures (or just use self-heating to get to a different temperature) and currents.  Your results won't be exact, but you should get close to the same number across several measurements because as temperature goes up, Vf goes down (and thereby power).  Based on your application, you can then decide how much additional heat-sinking you may need.

Between the LED's thermal impedance and the MCPB, I would guess you will probably be in the 5 C/W range from past experience.